# OpenCL: error use of undeclared identifier

Tags: conditional-statements, opencl, undeclared-identifier

I am trying to write a conditional statement in my opencl kernel. The code is in the image. If I remove the inner conditional statements the code runs fine, but otherwise I get the following error:

```
<program source>:157:23: warning: unused variable 'pyramid_1'
     float pyramid_1 = (largest_0 - largest_1) * distance_bw_x_coord * half_diff / 2 / 3;
           ^
<program source>:158:23: warning: unused variable 'pyramid_2'
     float pyramid_2 = (smallest_1 - smallest_0) * distance_bw_x_coord * half_diff /2 / 3;
           ^
<program source>:161:23: warning: unused variable 'pyramid_1'
     float pyramid_1 = distance_bw_x_coord * (largest_1 - smallest_1) * half_diff / 3;
           ^
<program source>:162:23: warning: unused variable 'pyramid_2'
     float pyramid_2 = half_diff * (largest_0 - smallest_1) * distance_bw_x_coord / 2 / 3;
           ^
<program source>:165:23: warning: unused variable 'pyramid_1'
     float pyramid_1 = distance_bw_x_coord * (largest_1 - largest_0) * half_diff / 3;
           ^
<program source>:166:23: warning: unused variable 'pyramid_2'
     float pyramid_2 = half_diff * (smallest_1 - smallest_0) * distance_bw_x_coord / 2 / 3;
           ^
<program source>:169:23: warning: unused variable 'pyramid_1'
     float pyramid_1 = (largest_0 - largest_1) * distance_bw_x_coord * half_diff / 2 / 3;
           ^
<program source>:170:23: warning: unused variable 'pyramid_2'
     float pyramid_2 = distance_bw_x_coord * (smallest_0 - smallest_0) * half_diff / 3;
           ^
<program source>:173:23: warning: unused variable 'pyramid_1'
     float pyramid_1 = half_diff * (largest_0 - smallest_0) * distance_bw_x_coord / 2 / 3;
           ^
<program source>:174:23: warning: unused variable 'pyramid_2'
     float pyramid_2 = distance_bw_x_coord * (largest_1 - smallest_1) * half_diff / 3;
           ^
<program source>:177:23: warning: unused variable 'pyramid_1'
     float pyramid_1 = distance_bw_x_coord * (largest_1 - largest_0) * half_diff / 3;
           ^
<program source>:178:23: warning: unused variable 'pyramid_2'
     float pyramid_2 = distance_bw_x_coord * (smallest_0 - smallest_1) * half_diff / 3;
           ^
<program source>:180:78: error: use of undeclared identifier 'pyramid_1'
     total_area += trapezoid_prism_vol + 2 (triangular_prism_vol + pyramid_1 + pyramid_2);    
                                                                   ^
<program source>:180:90: error: use of undeclared identifier 'pyramid_2'
     total_area += trapezoid_prism_vol + 2 (triangular_prism_vol + pyramid_1 + pyramid_2);    
                                                                               ^
```

[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fNIi.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! In future, please copy-paste your code into the question as text, not as an image/screenshot. Note that you can use triple backticks (```  code goes here ```) to surround code to show it as a monospaced block (with scrollbars if necessary). I've edited your question so the error messages are shown correctly, but I obviously can't do it for the code that's in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCL uses C's scoping rules. This means that if you declare a variable inside a `{ ... }` block, the variable only exists within this block.

So a correct way to write the type of code you are attempting to write is:

```
if (whatever)
{
    float pyramid_1; // declare the variable here
    if (condition1) {
        pyramid_1 = expression1; // assign a value here…
    }
    else if (condition2) {
    {
        pyramid_1 = expression2; // …and here…
    }
    // etc.

    /* You can use the result of computing pyramid_1's value here, as
     * we're still inside the same { } block it was declared in. */

    // …
}
```

Make sure to remove the `float` type specifier inside your `if`/`else if` blocks to make those statements *assignments*. If you don't, you just end up declaring new variables *with the same name* as the one declared outside those blocks. (This is called shadowing and usually a bad idea - in this case, the outer variable would never actually be updated.)